# the 'toObject()' function in fabric.js

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I set some user-defined attributes on the original canvas object,when I use `canvas.getActiveObject.toObject()`,the result can't show the user-defined attributes.What should I do that can make it show them?Or Maybe the method that I set attributes is wrong?Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and if possible, do provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide an array of `propertiesToInclude` when calling `Object.toObject()`. See the [API Doc here](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#toObject).

Example:

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    foo: 'bar', // property that should be included
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    left: 50,
    top: 50
});
var asObject = rect.toObject(['foo']);
console.log(object.foo); // 'bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

you should overide the prototype function toObject() and change it alittle bit, like this:

```
 //override prototype.toObject and add your custom properties here
    fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function(toObject) {
        return function() {
            return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                objectId: this.objectId,//my custom property
                _controlsVisibility:this._getControlsVisibility(),//i want to get the controllsVisibility
                typeTable:this.typeTable,//custom property
                txtType:this.txtType,//custom property
                customOptions: this.customOptions,//custom property
                emptySeats: this.emptySeats,//custom property
            });
        };
    })(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

after that when you get the object with toObject() you will get the properties that you entered above.

hope helps good luck.

Comment: i wonder why someone gave me negative vote. please enlight me whoever did that

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have tried it and it works.but @forrert  told me that the API DOC has a similar way to solve it too,anyway thanks

Comment: hello, of course it works 100%. we spend hours here to read ,understand and answer in order to help each other. Please be sure when you vote negative.
Personally i vote negative only if there is a stupid answer or irrelevant.

Comment: im'sorry, i don't understand why you think that I vote negative, i didn't vote negative to you at all ,maybe the other people did this.im a new here,my reputation is too low to vote negative or positive.I just want to thank you.